# Qt3D app triggers system sounds on any button press

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt3d

I checked out standard examples of Qt3D module but pressing any button triggers annoying osX system sounds, the ones when the wrong button is pressed, yet application's camera controller responds just fine in terms of moving camera around the scene. Any ideas what is the cause of system sound triggering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue of Qt5.7.0, updating to a newer version of Qt solved the problem.